# Converting iPhone XIB to iPad version with Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4, xib

With Xcode 3 in Interface Builder you were able to upscale an iPhone XIB file to an iPad version.  However in XCode 4 I cannot find a way to do this.  I would really prefer not to have to create the XIB again from scratch. Is there a way to do this like there was in Xcode 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked a few times, and unfortunately it seems (or rather, it's sure) that the option (*Create iPad Version Using Autosizing Masks*) has been removed from Xcode 4.

You will need to copy/paste the UI elements, and re-link them to your code.

**OR:** You are now allowed to install both Xcode 3 & 4 (simply choose a different folder to install it to). Since the nib files' format did not change, you can upgrade them in Xcode 3, and copy the converted files back into Xcode 4.

Comment: A better way has been discovered to do this that doesn't require installing another version of XCode. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347198/xcode-4-xib-create-ipad-version tells you how to convert an iPhone XIB to an iPad xib using only a text editor.