# Conversion of iPhone app to iPad in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I have an application which is already in App Store and developed with XCode 3.2 version. Now I am using latest X-Code version 4.3.3. In previous version we get the option that "Create iPad Conversion" but in XCode 4 we didn't have such kind of option so, I googled some articles and I did following steps:
1. Project navigator -> select target -> right click and selecte duplicate for ipad.
2. On summary tab select devices as "Universal".

When I run the application with iPad simulator I found that still there was showing iphone window with all its controls on Ipad simulator. I didn't get exact iPad window with resized controls.

I have total 14 .xib files with mainwindow.xib. What are the more steps that I have to follow to convert whole project into iPad?

Comment: Create a Universal Application

Comment: I already convert it as universal. I want some other steps if there are to make this application fully for ipad.

Comment: What steps are You needed for making a Universal aPP?

Comment: I explained in my question as I already made it to universal although its not done. So, I want to know is there any other process that I have to follow or I missed something?

Comment: Did you check with iPad and iPhone. is  app running on both device fine? then,nothing missed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you, Just converting it to universal might not resize your views to iPad size. In my case i had to change UI for iPad at few places in my application. Also, i had to convert my iPhone application to Universal. So, i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347198/xcode-4-xib-create-ipad-version). Now i have two xibs(iPad and iPhone) for each view as UI was different for both. Also naming was done as follows:

```
MyViewController.xib         //For iPhone
MyViewController~ipad.xib    //For iPad
```

If you need to convert the app for iPad only then, just convert the xibs to iPad size.