# Xib for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I have a Xib for iPhone and I need a similar view for iPad, only iPad size.

What is the best way of doing this? Can you put both views in the same Xib and somehow specify which one is shown?

Or do I need to be make 2 Xib files and 2 classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347198/xcode-4-xib-create-ipad-version

Comment: general speaking you can use the xib for the iPhone in the iPad project. The method initwithNib:@"YOUR XIB" is given the target xib name

Comment: If they are the same view, I would recommend making them dynamic of their frame size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using 1 class. I set the file owner of both XIB files to this same class.

I just used the name of the XIB file

So I have 2 xibFiles, iPadXib.xib and iPhoneXib.xib

```
NSString *nibFileName = (iPadVersion) ? @"iPadXib" : @"iPhoneXib";

ViewControllerName *vc = [[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:nibFileName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: If you name your XIB files MyThing~ipad.xib and MyThing~iphone.xib then you can call [[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyThing" and the correct XIB will automatically be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I need to be make 2 Xib files and 2 classes?

Actually, use three classes and 2 xibs. Like this:

1. MyClass
2. MyClass_iPhone: MyClass
3. MyClass_iPad: MyClass

And the two xibs. It gives you much more flexibility. Keep the common logic on the MyClass, and sub-class the other two for the iPhone and iPad Version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both iPhone and ipad  Create Universal App.
 Create only One XIB  and create all controls only once not need to do it separately.
   Draw the frame in coding.
 ie, Create  frame separate for both iphone and ipad.