# How to make seperate xib for iphone from already existing one for ipad

Tags: ios, xib, ios-autolayout

I am having iPad specific application. I want to play same on iPhone also. My app having xib which used size class "wRegular hRegular" with many auto layout constraints. I want to covert this to wAny hAny size class. 
I know there are two way to achieve this either using auto layout or creating another xib file for iPhone only.
I want to go with separate xib files But how to make this files in XCode 7?
And how this will work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with loading a separate XIB for iPad or iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306346/trouble-with-loading-a-separate-xib-for-ipad-or-iphone) or [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496218/xib-for-iphone-and-ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496218/xib-for-iphone-and-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Just create new XIB file with name whatever you want to give and load the UIViewController using following code

```
ViewControllerName *vc = [[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
```

In ViewController override - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil method in which check for device is iPhone or iPad using following code

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
     NSString * nibNameOrNil;
     if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ){
        // iPad
        nibNameOrNil = @“iPad_XIB_NAME”
     } else {
        // iPhone
     }
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self)
     {
        // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
}
```

this will call your XIB according to your device type.