# going from Iphone to ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've created full app for iPhone, but I need to make iPad version. mostly the app is lists, but login screen, logo and cells are too small (just to repeat - it was created for iPhone). Is there any way to create iPad user interface or stretch phone views?

Thatnks for your help. Btw sorry if it's duplicate of some similar question. Just couldn't find it (maybe bad keywords).

Comment: R u using storyboards?

Comment: why don't you just make iPad xibs and add them to your logic?

Comment: No. forgot to mention its xib files. Just so it might work on 4.2iOS version

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY-btZ-KjX0) video tutorial will help then.

Comment: Andrey i need a really fast solution. Making ne xibs just will take much time. Because it's not small app...

Comment: A quick google search came up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488280/converting-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib)

Comment: i don't think you can have some magic quick solution. i think you should either make iPad xibs or set size in code

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should have separate XIBs for iPad & iPhone.  Now, if you want to try and save some work and start from the iPhone XIBs as your base point, you should take a look at the top two answers from this question:

[Xcode 4 .xib Create iPad Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347198/xcode-4-xib-create-ipad-version)