# How to create iPad xib file in iPhone specific project

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I did a project few days back for iPhone but now i want to add iPad xib file into it. As features are enhancing. But the problem is that, at starting i selected an iPhone target for xib file not universal project.

So now i want to add xib for iPad's .

I created a new xib file for iPad but don't know how to load this on iPad instead of default xib file which is created for iPhone.

I have been checking a lot of other questions but didn't find any correct answer.[Xcode 4 .xib Create iPad Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347198/xcode-4-xib-create-ipad-version) But its not working for me

I'm working on Xcode 5 and iOS 7.0.x

Comment: Did you try to name your xib in this manner: if xib for iPhone is named as `name.xib` then for iPad set name to `name~ipad.xib`. In this case iPad version would be loaded automatically when you run application on iPad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For automatic loading xib for iPad add `~ipad` to the name of xib file.
For example:
If name of xib for iPhone version is `CustomVC.xib`
then for iPad version use `CustomVC~ipad.xib`.
When you create object of vc `CustomVC *vc = [[CustomVC alloc] init];` iOS will automatically choose correct xib file depending on platform (iPhone or iPad) where application is run.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Its working amazingly. I just create a new iPad xib file with same name and just add ~ipad and its working . Perfect

Answer (score 0):

1. On the general tab for the target settings you'll find "Deployment Info"
2. Change "Devices" to "Universal" (You've probably already done this)  The first time you do this it should ask you if you want to copy the iPhone storyboard to create an iPad storyboard.  Choose the correct answer.
3. Select iPad from the tabs below devices.
4. Change "Main Interface" to your new storyboard.

Comment: I am not using story board. Just using simple view's

Comment: Then see Visput's comment about naming and A'sa's answer.  Maybe clarify how you're loading your initial view controller in your question :)